# Dynamically update form action based on selected <option>

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is what I am trying to do.. I want a dropdown in HTML with a submit button that changes based on the value of the dropdown.

So, when I have this:

```
<select name="sizes" id="select13">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="20x30">20x30</option>
<option value="30x30">30x30</option>
...
</select>
```

What I need is a button that checks what the value is. If value = 20x30 then use URL www.example.com/20x30

If value is 30x30 then use URL www.example.com/30x30

I am far from a PHP expert, so anyone that is able to set me off in the right direction would be a life saver :)

Comment: Try looking at javascript to do this - php cannot process client side changes

Comment: Someone edited the title and tags, the original question specifically asked for a PHP solution.

Comment: This could be done in PHP by returning a redirect.

Comment: Is this `select` element purely for the purpose of navigation? Or is it within a form that the user submits to get processed by your application?

Comment: It is within a form that get's processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this:

**Javascript:**

```
function goto() {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/"+document.getElementById('select13').value;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="sizes" id="select13">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="20x30">20x30</option>
    <option value="30x30">30x30</option>
</select>
<button onclick='goto()'>Go</button>
```

When you click on the 'GO' button it redirects to example.com/(the selected value).

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yffa5/) with an exmaple.

---

**EDIT** to fit your comment:

```
function goto() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('select13').value;
    if (selection != 'All') {
        //window.location = "http://www.example.com/"+selection;
        alert("http://www.example.com/" + selection);
    } else {
        alert("Error: You must pick something");
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you want to submit a form and then do the redirection. The PHP code would be as follows:

```
<?php
    //Process your form without echoing anything before the header function.

    if($_REQUEST['sizes'] != 'All'){
        header('location:http://example.com/'.$_REQUEST['sizes']);
    }
    else{
        header('location:http://example.com/form.php');
    }
```

Comment: This is the best answer if the `select` element is purely for the purpose of navigation.

Comment: Ah, works great :)

http://strooi-zout.eu/test/

However, how do I display the error alert message when value = all?

I want to force people to pick something :)

Comment: Kyle Willis asks: "If I want the action to be a 'mailto', what do I put into the 'action' in the HTML?"

Answer (score 6):

some simple Javascript would suffice:

```
<form id="FORM_ID" action="DEFAULT_ACTION">
    <select name="sizes" id="select13">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="20x30">20x30</option>
        <option value="30x30">30x30</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('select13').onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById('FORM_ID').action = '/'+this.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what the asker is looking for. By "submit button" I think he means the action target of the form.

Comment: The submit button will only go to the form action. If you don't supply a form action, then the action becomes the current URL

Comment: Note that my comment was simply agreeing with your answer ;)

Comment: i thought you were the OP, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an `onchange` event for your dropdown:

```
document.getElementById("select13").onchange = function() {
    var currentVal = this.value;

    if (currentVal == "20x30") {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```