# Order forms field calculation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bitcoin

I am building a order form for buying Bitcoins via JotForm.Maybe someone could give me a head start here. My order form has a a few fields I have a field with current Bitcoin price which is retrieved with PHP via JSON. What I would like to do is when a user enters a amount of bitcoins he would like to order the field of **TOTAL SUM** would refresh automatically based on amount he entered like  "2xcurent price". Any help is like really appreciated!

This is how it looks visually:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2k4fgw.jpg

Part of my form code is here:

```
 <h2 id="header_13" class="form-header">
        Order form
      </h2>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_15">
    <div id="cid_15" class="form-input-wide">
      <div id="text_15" class="form-html">
        <p>
          <strong>
           Bitcoin price USD:<?php echo $usd; ?>
          </strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_18">
    <div id="cid_18" class="form-input-wide">
      <div id="text_18" class="form-html">
        <p>
          <strong>
            Total Sum :
          </strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_3">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_3" for="input_3"> Email: </label>
    <div id="cid_3" class="form-input-wide">
      <input type="email" class=" form-textbox validate[Email]" id="input_3" name="q3_elPastas" size="25" value="" maxlength="38" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_9">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_9" for="input_9"> Bitcoin amount: </label>
    <div id="cid_9" class="form-input-wide">
      <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[Numeric]" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_9" name="q9_pasirinktosValiutos9" size="25" value="" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_10">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_10" for="input_10"> Bitcoin address: </label>
    <div id="cid_10" class="form-input-wide">
      <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[AlphaNumeric]" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_10" name="q10_bitcoinAdresas10" size="25" value="" maxlength="37" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_14">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_14" for="input_14">  </label>
    <div id="cid_14" class="form-input-wide">
      <div class="form-single-column"><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_14_0" name="q14_input14[]" value="I Agree to receive newsletter" />
          <label for="input_14_0">I Agree to receive news letter </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_12">
    <div id="cid_12" class="form-input-wide">
      <div style="width:100%; text-align:Left;">
        <script id="jcf_custom_field" type="text/javascript" src="http://js.jotform.com/WidgetsServer.min.js"></script>
        <iframe onload="widgetFrameLoaded(12)" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="custom-field-frame" id="customFieldFrame_12" src="" style="border:none;width:400px; height: 45px">
        </iframe>
        <div>
          <input id="input_12" class="form-hidden widget-required form-widget" type="hidden" name="q12_clickTo" value="">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_2">
    <div id="cid_2" class="form-input-wide">
      <div style="text-align:center" class="form-buttons-wrapper">
        <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
          ORDER!
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li style="display:none">
    Should be Empty:
    <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What research have you done in this so far? You are absolutely not the first person trying to calculate values dynamically from data entered into a form, so …?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically update form action based on selected <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075138/dynamically-update-form-action-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply using an array of objects. So for example, I am accepting registrations. So to get the total price I go about it like this:

```
var registrants = [];

registrants.push({ price: 30 });
registrants.push({ price: 10 });
registrants.push({ price: 20 });

var totalPrice = 0;

for(var x = 0; x < registrants.length; x++){
    totalPrice += registrants[x]["price"];
}
```

and you would just update the price property of the corresponding registrant when appropriate.